# Nesetd checkboxlist tile in flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

[I want a list like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziL1y.jpg)

I want a list with check box take to a list of another check box

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget with **Padding** widget

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
  child: Container(), //Put your widget here
 )
```